# Enumeration relying on integer boolean conversion

Tags: c++, boolean, enumeration

In my compiler project, I have an enumeration that goes like

```
enum Result {
  No,
  Maybe,
  Yes
};
```

I have put `No` explicitly at the first position, so that i can rely on the boolean evaluation to `false`. If my compiler is not sure about something, and has to wait for facts until runtime, its analysis functions will return `Maybe`. Used like

```
if(!typesEqual(t1, t2)) {
  diagnose(types_unequal) << t1 << t2;
}
```

I wonder whether you or your company considers it bad style not to compare to `No` explicitly

```
if(typesEqual(t1, t2) == No) { /* ... */ }
```

Comparing explicitly seems wordy to me, but relying on the implicit boolean conversion somehow makes me feel guilty. Have you had that feeling before, and how have you dealt with it?

Comment: I think i'm going to make it CW, because it seems more of a style question!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'd feel guilty about it as well, because *from reading the code above* what would you expect the boolean `typesEqual()` expression to return for a `Maybe`? Would it return true? Maybe! Would it return false? Maybe! We don't know - that's the entire point of the enum. That's why it makes sense to explicitly compare to `No`, even though it's more verbose.

Answer (score 3):

I don't usually use an explicit comparison with zero for integral or pointer types since the conversion-to-boolean is well-defined and obvious.

However, I always use an explicit comparison for enumerations, *just in case* someone changes the definition of the enumeration.  You can never be sure that someone won't change the enumeration later, after all.

Relying on the underlying numeric value of an enumerator just seems like a bad idea.

Answer (score 1):

This seems similar to [Boost.Tribool](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_43_0/doc/html/tribool/tutorial.html). Tribool supports conversions to bool for use in conditional statements, which would seem to suggest that implicit conversion to bool in a case such as this is not bad, at least according to the Boost organization (whom I have found to be fairly reasonable).

Answer (score 0):

What I don't like is that it is asymmetric.

E.g. what you really wanted somewhere was

```
if(typesEqual(t1, t2) == Yes) {
    do_something();
}
```

but by accident you wrote

```
if(typesEqual(t1, t2)) {
    do_something();
}
```

It seems somehow strange/ugly that you can use the boolean trick for No but not for Yes.

I think I would solve it by renaming the function to `tryCompareTypes(t1, t2)`, and change your enum to

```
enum Result {
  Maybe,
  No,
  Yes
};
```

So `tryCompareTypes()` returns 0 if it "failed" to definitively decide whether the types are equal, otherwise it returns either No or Yes, both of which are nonzero and hence indicate "success".